# what does this question about a matrix mean?

Tags: matrices

here is a question says :

[image: matrix]

**what does that mean ?**

I did my best to solve this question myself but i didn't find a way to solve it

is this question possible or there is something else that i don't understand it

**the matrix is square** ..

**how it changes to singular?**

Answer (score 2):

A singular matrix is a matrix which does not have an inverse. A matrix has an inverse if and only if its determinant is nonzero. Take the determinant and find the value(s) of $\alpha$ which makes the determinant zero. Then just take the $\alpha$ such that it means the condition of the problem - that is, $0 \leq \alpha <2\pi$.

Comment: but ! we know that a matrix of order " size " $n*n$ is called a square matrix .. and the above matrix is $2*2$ matrix .. so even if it has not an inverse it is still square ?? confusion ??

Comment: We only consider the determinant for square matrices and the only consider matrices to even *possibly* having an inverse if the matrix is square. But keep in mind just because a matrix is square doesn't mean that it will have an inverse. So to sum up, for the question asking about a determinant of a matrix or its inverse, the question only makes sense if the matrix is square. But just being square isn't enough. There is more to check - that is, that the determinant of the matrix is **not** zero. You need both square AND nonzero determinant.